# SSIS Variable Naming Limitations

Tags: variables, object, ssis, naming-conventions

I have an object variable named FileHeaderRecords which holds the first row of a file. I have a Script Component to isolate this row, then I count the amount of row (should be 1) with a Row Counter, then I load it into Dataset.

I added a Data Viewer between the Row Counter and the Dataset and it shows there is a row being loaded into the Dataset. This is all hanlded within my Data Flow.

I have a Script Task that the Data Flow connects to and in this I am counting the rows in the FileHeaderRecords object variable.

The issue is it is returning 0, but if I change the name of the variable to "test" for example, it returns 1 which is correct?

Is the FileHeaderRecords variable name being confused with a system variable name or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the FileHeaderRecords is spelled correctly in the Script Task?

Comment: Along with Minh's point, these are case sensitive. Also, depending on your version of SSIS, be aware that you could have created two FileHeaderRecords SSIS Variables: one on the Data Flow and one at Control Flow level. Prior to 2012, wherever your mouse has focus is the location a Variable is created on. The fact that you change a variable name and it doesn't blow up leads me to believe this is the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made sure to copy and paste the variable name and I did check to see if there were other variables with that name by clicking the "Show All Variables" button and there doesnt seem to be any other variables with the same name. I do have another variable called FileHeaderCount which holds the row counter of the records. Im going to change this name to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: So, if I change the object variable to test it works, if i change it so testFileHeaderRecords it works, but if I change it to FileHeaderRecordstest, it returns no records. So weird!

Comment: Also, make that recordset not dataset**

Comment: Without some concrete examples of what your package looks like, your code etc, I'm afraid we can't provide any insight beyond what's been delivered

Comment: As it turns out you cannot reuse recordsets stuffed into SSIS object variables across multiple tasks.
There is a solution though:

For some reason this empties your object variable. What???

First you have to convert your datatable to an ADODB.Recordset. The code to do that is in the article linked below. Just copy and paste to your script code.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToRecordset.aspx

Comment: You can also use the multitask to put the records into multiple object variables when you first create the recordsets then use each one separately.

Comment: Yes I have encountered this before.  If you want to use the same recordset in two different tasks, you need to populate two object variables to use one in each task.   You can't reuse the same variable.   I encountered it so long ago, I forget why it is, but yes, it is known.

Comment: Yup it is definitley weird. What I ended up doing was in the dataflow I had temp variables that are used for the recordsets. Next I created a script task which inserted these values into the variables which I could then use thoughout my package  

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Temp"].Value);
Dts.Variables["User::Table"].Value = dt;

Then whenever I wanted to use the Table vaiable, I copied it to a local datatable variable.

DataTable dt = (Dts.Variables["User::Table"].Value as DataTable).Copy();

Comment: You will also have to be careful with CheckPoints adding peculiar. Watch out when you use Object Variables and Checkpoints.